# Selecting different backgrounds

Tags: backgrounds

Hello I am trying to create a document with multiple pages. However, I need to add a specific background to the first page and another background for the rest of the pages.

I am currently using:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[pages=1,2]{background}

\backgroundsetup
{scale=1.0, color=black, opacity=1.0, angle=0, 
contents={
\checkoddpage
         \ifoddpage
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{1.pdf}
         \else
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{2.pdf}
        \fi}
}
```

I would like to use something like this instead of ifoddpages.

```
\if page = 1 
    \includegraphics{...} 
else 
    \includegraphics{...}
```

Comment: Please try the following: `\ifnum\value{page}>1 \includegraphics{...}\else\includegraphics{...}\fi`. There is a space between `1` and `\includegraphics{...}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this solution, but according to [this thread](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21514), in order to detect the page number, you can do this:

```
\ifnum\value{page}>1 \includegraphics{...}\else\includegraphics{...}\fi
```

Comment: Thank you, my issue was resolved using                                           \ifnum\thepage=1 command